# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

So about an hour ago, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11865870/1015495). In short order,  it collected some downvotes, with no explanation. So, simply put, could our lovely meta community help me understand what is wrong with this question and why it garnered such disdain?

Comment: Off the top of my head - too much code...  You might have been able to post only the relevant code...  Or maybe they feel your username is deceptive ;)

Comment: Aside from the "wall of code" it looks okay to me.

Comment: I fear it's one of those "this doesn't read cleanly" type of downvotes. The wall of code and large block of text don't make it easy to visually parse. Not something that I would downvote, but all I could come up with.

Comment: Looks good to me too, little too much code (as others have said) but not vote downable, have +1 back.

Comment: Perhaps you can split your block of text into a couple of paragraphs. That allows for some visual separation. A nitpick issue though.

Comment: @ForkandBeard Aw, you make me all warm and fuzzy inside.

Answer (score 4):

I can only guess at the reasons for the down votes, as none of them are my own. But this is the only thing that hits me to account for three such votes (one can be easily explained as a fluke)...

Your question has a lot of code for what is essentially a fairly simple issue. The code, in fact, makes it more difficult to answer this particular question, in my opinion (and perhaps the opinions of the down voters).

The answer is actually really simple, by comparison: Create the same controls every time the page loads, even on postback, and do it earlier in the page lifecycle than `Page_Load`. It's possible one or more of the down votes was due to thinking you had not researched your question enough, due to the relative simplicity of the answer.

Comment: Note, again, that I did not down vote and have not down voted now that the question has been brought to my attention.

Comment: Since meta isn't the place to discuss the solution, would you mind answering my question (if you're not already doing that)? I'd have some questions for you, but I don't want to clutter up meta.

Comment: @AndrewBarber The question remains though, did you downvote that question? ;)

Comment: Andrew - Did you, or did you not, downvote the question in question?

Comment: Although I'm sure it comes up all the time I'm not actually sure how simple this question is *if you don't know the answer*.

Comment: @Bart and jadarnel27 I have checked my copious records, and I can say - with 98.473% certainty - that I did *not* downvote in this instance! ;)

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I am getting ready to head out the door, but I will when I get back this afternoon, if someone else has not already.